# fullcalendar 4, callback when calendar is completely rendered

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Fullcalendar version 3 used to have a callback function that would fire once all events have rendered.  I would use this:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function( view ) { 
    load_call_list();
}
```

load_call_list is a function I made to count certain events based on their status.  It also queries my database for other information.

Using fullcalendar 4, once the calendar has fully loaded and all the events have rendered, I want to call that function. Here's how my calendar is initialized now...

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendar_full = document.getElementById('calendar_full');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendar_full, {
        height: 700,
        selectMirror: true,
        events: {
            url: 'ajax_get_json.php?what=location_appointments'
        },
  ....
```

I suppose my lack of understanding about javascript is limiting me in understanding where I can catch when the calendar events have all fully loaded.

I thought about using eventrender, but I don't want the load_call_list to be fired every time as my database is queried with that function too.

I tried using jquery $(document).ready(function(){}) but that fires before the events have been rendered.

Any advice on how to accomplish this?

Comment: _"I tried using jquery $(document).ready(function(){}) but that fires before the events have been rendered."_ ...yes, that fires when your web page has initially loaded all the HTML and CSS. It doesn't wait for AJAX requests or JavaScript code to be executed. It's just the jQuery equivalent of the "DomContentLoaded" line in your code above. https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: P.S. I guess you may have read the [upgrade guide](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3) already? It talks about the removal of this method and the reasons why, and gives some (admittedly fairly minimal) advice about what to do instead.

Comment: One thing you could do instead is implement a completely custom event source function (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function). That way you could a) have code to count the number of events received when your ajax call finishes, or b) include a count of the data as a property in the response data. You also mention that load_call_list queries your database again. I would suggest that here is an opportunity to save yourself a HTTP request by including that data up-front in your initial response.

Comment: e.g the events function would run an ajax call which returns an object e.g. `{ eventCount: 30, events: [ ...array of events that fullCalendar needs ... ], otherData: { .... whatever data is currently fetched by load_call_list ... }`. Maybe that would work for you. Then you'd just pass the events themselves to fullCalendar e.g. `successCallback(data.events);` and do whatever you like with the rest of the data. No need to wait for everything to render, and no need to make a separate AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks, ADyson.  Yeah, I read the docs and was just secretly hoping to find a bit of an easier way. i had thought about the events-function callback idea.  I'll give that more thought!  I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so how about this?  I can use the loading function.  When the calendar is done loading, I can call my load_call_list function.  I am using a bool variable to stop it from firing everytime the calendar loads without a page refresh (like when cycling through months or weeks, for instance).

When the page first loads, I have a var called initial_load = true.  When the calendar has finished 'loading', if this is true, then I'll call my function and set my initial_load to false so it won't just fire off as I explained before.

```
<script>
//set initial_load so when the calendar is done loading, it'll get call list info
var initial_load = true;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


    var calendar1 = document.getElementById('calendar_mini');
    var calendar_mini = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendar1, {
       ....
       ....
       loading: function(bool) {

        if (bool) {
            $('.loader').show();
            $('#show_cancelled_appts').hide();
            $('#show_rescheduled_appts').hide();
            $('#print_calendar').hide();
        } else {
            $('.loader').hide();
            $('#show_cancelled_appts').show();
            $('#show_rescheduled_appts').show();
            $('#print_calendar').show();

            //once it's done loading, load call list with current date stuff; set 
            initial_load = false so it doesn't keep loading call list when calendar changes while cycling months/weeks/etc
                var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                if (initial_load) {
                    load_call_list(today);
                    initial_load = false;
                }


        }
 },
```

It does actually work!  Thoughts on that?  Is this okay programming?  I don't see any downside as of now.

Comment: loading is false when the calendar itself is loaded, not when ajax loaded events are positionned