# Getting actual height of fully rendered calendar page (FullCalendar)

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66189654/getting-wrong-value-for-clientheight) it is not obvious at all to determine the actual height of a fully rendered calendar page. Using `$(window).on('load', function(){ ... });` does not work as it does not wait for AJAX requests or JavaScript code to be executed. The result is a wrong info on height, because the page is not fully rendered (because events still come rushing in from the AJAX request) and has therefore not reached it's final height. So the following does not work. `clientHeight` gives `219` instead of `1165` pixel height:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    let h = document.getElementById("calendar").clientHeight; 
    console.log(h);  // 219
    console.log(div.scrollHeight); // 219
    console.log(div.clientHeight); // 219
    console.log(div.offsetHeight); // 221
    console.log($('#cbody').height()); // 188.75

    let w = document.getElementById("cbody").clientWidth;
    console.log(w);  // 1221, works!
});
```

However, the above function works if I do it in a `setTimeout(function() {` but that's not clear code, because I do never know how long it will take to load all the resources and therefore can't determine a proper timeout -- it will be always too short or too long.

The solution might be to get some kind of event when all calendar events have been rendered to the page, because that's what determines it's height. As ADyson stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56461994/fullcalendar-4-callback-when-calendar-is-completely-rendered) the FullCalendar's [successCallback](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) might be used for that but I don't know how to approach from there. My `eventSources` are loaded like this:

```
      eventSources: [
          {
            url: HOLIDAY_URL,
            backgroundColor: 'coral',
            display: 'background'
          },
          {
            url: EVENT_URL,
          }
      ],
```

How to use the `successCallback` on this? `EVENT_URL` gets a JSON feed which already contains all info and tags like `start` `end` `color` and such and does not need to be mapped. Or maybe there is a completely other approach to get the actual height?

Comment: I have the similar issue with you. It is because the height you are getting is not after all events are rendered. Eager to be get answered. When v3 was having [eventAfterRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventAfterRender), I am sure it would be a valuable method to get  all kinds of height after all events are rendered. But the method has removed by upgrading the version. So I also need to a new feature like the method hopefully. For now, I guess you should use [eventSourceSuccess](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSourceSuccess) for the latest fullcalendar version.

Comment: I just tried `eventSourceSuccess` and it does not seem to be reliable. Sometimes it provides the correct height, sometimes not. If you say you're having the same issue, it sounds like it did not work for you either. What is your actual workaround to deal with the issue?

Comment: refer to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66142997/how-to-know-all-events-are-rendered-in-fullcalendar-v5